# Why is this user not seen as a link?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I noticed in this thread [Why can you have a column named ORDER in DB2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245592/why-can-you-have-a-column-named-order-in-db2) the user with accepted answer ( David Hughes ) not a link to his profile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He [doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32443/dave-hughes). His profile was deleted for whatever reason.

Answer (score 2):

see here

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/